# Replication on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, replication, database-replication

I'm working with a practice about repication, I'm trying to make it with an ubuntu and i'm struggled with the file my.cnf and now i can't start the service of mysql. Does anybody have any idea how can i fix it?

Comment: We have no idea what the problem might be, until you examine the error log and tell us something about what went wrong, based on what you see there.

Comment: The problem was that i saw a tutorial about it, on the video they said that i had to modify the file my.cnf but i couldn't save the changes. Then i assigned permissions of modifying. To be specific i forced the changes to that file, but when i could save it. I tried to start the service of my sql but o couldn't

Comment: Find the error log.  It may be in /var/log/mysql/, depending on the distribution.